# Mongoose model required and with default

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I created mongoose model with a field named "phoneNumber":

```
...
phoneNumber: {
    type: 'String',
    required: true,
    default: ''
},
...
```

Whenever I create a new record of that model, I got validation failed exception:

```
 Path `phoneNumber` is required
```

This is happens even though I set default value.
What is incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting the default value to empty string and in JavaScript empty string is a `falsy` value. Thus the required check fails and you get that validation message.

> Read more about Falsy values at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: what is the proposeof using required with default? if there is a default then what case the require should throw error?

Comment: @adirabargil from [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html): **Note**: Mongoose only applies a default if the value of the path is strictly `undefined`.

Comment: @Farhan that's lame on Mongoose's part. IMO they should've checked for `null`/`undefined`, nothing more.